# Help creating ubuntu boot usb

Tags: boot, system-installation

hope someone can shed some light on this.

I'm trying to create a USB boot for Ubuntu to replace windows on my laptop. I have done this before on a Windows pc,however the only device I have to create the USB at present is my android tablet.

Is it possible to create the USB for a windows laptop from an android tablet?

Thanks.

Comment: You have a USB on-the-go cable and enough space in the tablet for a Ubuntu iso?

Comment: Yeah I have plenty of space, I'm using a 4 gig USB and I've got about 9 gig free on my Xperia tablet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu Using Cell Phone Only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925400/installing-ubuntu-using-cell-phone-only)

Answer (score 0):

Use an app that emulates a terminal on your android device (look in the market) to issue the `dd` tool to write a downloaded iso to your usb or sd-card.

`dd if=/path/to/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/yourusborsdcard`

be careful however, this can damage your tablet data if handled improperly. always use a usb/sd-card without any important data on it.

edit: a terminal emulator like [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Aside the HATEthePLOT answer, you can use [DriveDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softwarebakery.drivedroid) (requires **root**):

With it, you can use your own phone as a bootable device.

It even has a friendly menu where you can select a distro to download:

[image: DriveDroid download distro menu]