# Creating a bootable USB to install Ubuntu on a PC with no OS

Tags: live-usb, usb-installation

I want to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my PC through USB.
My PC has no OS installed.

How can I create a bootable USB?
Is there any file which we just copy to USB and the USB become bootable?

Comment: Do you have another PC which you can use in order to make a bootable USB stick?

Comment: Canonical no longer sells Live USB's or CD's. I think your only options are to either have a friend who will make you a boot USB or CD on their computer or to order one from Amazon, Ebay, etc. Price should be under $10.

Comment: I could find nothing to do with "Creating a bootable USB to install Ubuntu on a PC with no OS" on the page the DPP recommended. Every answer there includes downloading the ISO, which is difficult without an OS.

Comment: Maybe this link will help: [www.osdisc.com/products/ubuntu](https://www.osdisc.com/products/ubuntu), scroll down to find USB pendrives -- You can check the drive (that it is correct) according to [Checking the iso file and the boot drive - detailed tips](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13511608#post13511608) 'Check the disk for defects'

Comment: If I have another PC,why did I asked. I have downloaded the. iso file and I also have an usb

Comment: On what type of media is the ISO stored? Do you have a friend that can install the ISO to USB using Unetbootin, Rufus, mkusb or other Live USB creator? If computer is UEFI you can just extract the ISO to USB.

Comment: I have downloaded the .iso file on my android device. Its not rooted because it is in warranty till 16 January. If it is rooted I install Drive droid

Comment: It is possible to install Ubuntu from a cell phone see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/925400/installing-ubuntu-using-cell-phone-only

Comment: The problem is that my phone is not rooted. Is there any way to use 'DriveDroid' without rooting my device?

Comment: @user841687 I was thinking that using dd inside Terminal Emulator to write to a flash drive or MicroSD might not require rooting the phone. I always get a little scared of dd though. I had to root my wife's phone to get drive droid to work.

Comment: Do you mean Terminal emulator can do this without rooting android? If so,what's the command?

Comment: @user841687 It looks like it is going to work but I am stuck trying to figure out the path to the thumb drive in dd. I don speak so good Android.

Comment: Now, What to do?  Is there any file which we just copy and paste to usb and the usb become bootable?

Comment: Now, What to do?  Is there any file which we just copy and paste to usb and the usb become bootable?  I tried just extracting the .iso file to usb, but, it not worked.

Comment: Or Is there any way to root my android without voiding warranty? I researched this many times. Some are saying "Kingroot doesn't voids warranty", some are saying "It voids warranty".

Comment: I tried Terminal Emulator using dd if=/storage/extSdCard/DATA/Linux/ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64 of=/dev/bus/001/002 , and I get "Permission denied". I used Kingroot to root my phone, it is pretty easy to switch back and forth, root or no root, not sure about warranty, mine was expired years ago.

Comment: Which emulator did you used? I tried an app called "exa gear strategy" to run an windows application called "rufus" to create a bootable usb. The exe file ran but it can't detect the usb.

Comment: Which emulator did you used? I tried an app called "exa gear strategy" to run an windows application called "rufus" to create a bootable usb. The exe file ran but it can't detect the usb.

Comment: I tried both "Terminal Emulator", (green and blue android eye icon), and "Shell Terminal" best luck with the first.

Comment: Hello. Is there anyone who can help me? I accidently formatted my hard drive while installing ubuntu 16.04 LTS.