# Accidentally deleted a partition, now I am finding just the grub rescue window. What should I do?

Tags: grubrescue

I accidentally deleted a partition that probably was the one with the os I was using. Now it shows this. How can I regain access to my Computer? I did a dual boot of Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS with WIndows 10.

Comment: You may be able to use testdisk or parted rescue from Ubuntu live installer. This example is where Windows deleted partition, but should be the same: Parted rescue seems easier than testdisk
https://askubuntu.com/questions/665445/upgraded-to-windows-10-on-dual-boot-and-cant-boot-to-ubuntu-partition

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 1):

Did that partition contained both Ubuntu and Windows10 ? 
You cannot install Ubuntu and windows in the same partition. In that case you can get access from the other OS.

Anyway,if that is not possible, the easiest solution seems to be reinstalling Ubuntu 18.04. 
I hope you have the live USB or DVD of Ubuntu at you installed earlier. Just insert it and enter the bios. Boot from USB/DVD and install it. You will be fine. 
After installing Ubuntu you can dual boot it with windows10 if you wish.

In case you don't have live USB/DVD, you can use your phone as a bootable device :

[1. Installing Ubuntu Using Cell Phone Only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925400/installing-ubuntu-using-cell-phone-only)

[2. Boot Linux ISO From Android Phone](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/boot-linux-iso-from-android-phone)

[3. How to Boot Into Linux from Your Android Phone](https://lifehacker.com/5990655/how-to-boot-into-linux-from-your-android-phone)

Comment: HI, I don't have that dvd I used earlier. I suppose there was a burn needed, by rufus, which I can't do from my mobile. Is there any way?

Comment: You got android I hope...I edited my answer with some links..hope they help you..I never booted from phone so I wouldn't be able to help with that any further.

Comment: @Spectra I find #3 very interesting, thank you.

Comment: *Did that partition contained both Ubuntu and Windows10 ?* A partition **cannot** contain both Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia , I know that a partition cannot contain both ubuntu and windows, that why I asked him. Cause,in that case he need not worry, if he deleted one part (ubuntu / windows )he can gain access from the other part (windows/ubuntu). I assumed he would understand. Sorry for not making it clear. Edited the answer.

Comment: @Spectra It's not so simple. *gain access from the other part* is true if you're booting from an EFI partition (UEFI mode) but if BIOS, with the bootloader (Grub) in the MBR, once you delete the Ubuntu partition, Windows will not boot either. The MBR is very small and only contains Grub's "first stage", the rest being in the Ubuntu partition.

Answer (score 0):

Since you indicated you only have a mobile phone and it's unlikely you will have access to the ability to create a new DVD or USB disk, here are some tips you can try from the GRUB console:

First, you need to set "pager" mode in GRUB so that you can read the output of commands if they go off the screen:

```
grub> set pager=1
```

Next you want to see what disks GRUB can see, if any:

```
grub> ls
```

This will output something like:

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)
```

Here it's showing there are two partitions on `(hd0)` - if there are no partitions listed then you somehow deleted your entire disk or all of it's partitions. If there are disks there you can try accessing their contents:

```
grub> ls (hd0,0)/
```

You might see output that looks like a Windows disk, assuming it has a `C:\Windows` directory and a `C:\Users` directory (note the `C:\` wont be displayed by GRUB) and you can follow these instructions to tell GRUB to manually boot that partition:

[Boot Windows from GRUB rescue command prompt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71555/boot-windows-from-grub-rescue-command-prompt)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after I deleted the **kali Linux**  partition.In my case, I still wanted to boot to windows; my grub default partition had been set to kali Linux, so it was difficult to boot to windows; I only got the `grub loading` 
`welcome to grub` `error no such partition

**Kindly follow the steps below to try and fix it**
*This is because Windows and Linux share the boot partition, and deleting Linux causes the boot partition to be deleted*

1. if you have a ready-made system installation disk or the conditions to make one? You can use the cmd of the system installation disk to repair.
2. this requires a system installation disk because the boot partition has disappeared, and we can’t rebuild it with BIOS alone.
3. Please go to go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10. Download MediaCreationTool on another computer, Prepare an empty USB disk, run MediaCreationTool and choose to create installation media for other computers.
4. Go to the BIOS and change the boot ordering Windows Boot Manager to the top.
   No need to reinstall Windows

5.Can you boot into Windows? If not, try this:

Restart your computer and immediately press the boot key to enter the boot menu (On my IdeaPad S145, it's F12)
Select Windows Boot Manager using the arrow keys and hit enter.
Are you able to boot into Windows?If yes, click on Start>Power and by holding down the shift key, click on Restart.When you're presented with an advanced (blue screen) menu, clickonTroubleshoot>Advanced Options>UEFI Firmware Settings>Restart
This will enter you into your Computer BIOSSelect the Boot tab using the arrow keys and select Windows Boot managerOn the side, you will see the instructions to move it up or down. Press that key to move Windows Boot Manager to the top. (It is F6 on my laptop)Then press F10 to save changes and exit.You should now boot into Windows

6.If it is only the *

> grub rescue

- you see in the boot menu > , that is not the boot menu.

When you turn on your computer, immediately, without waiting even a second, keep pressing F12 (No need of fn key) until you hear a beep sound or something pops up on your screen.

If still you cannot access Windows, follow the steps below:

-) Create a Windows 10 installation media on another PC. Go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows10 and click on Download tool

-) Run the tool and select Create an installation medium for another device. Insert a blank USB drive with at **least 4 GB of space**. All the data in it will be deleted. After doing that, wait for the tool to complete its process. This might take a long time.

-) Insert the USB drive into the affected computer and turn it on. Immediately upon startup, keep pressing F12

-) Select the USB drive and hit enter (You might know these steps if you dual-booted Linux)

-) When you are booted into the Windows 10 installation environment, select your preferred language and click on Next. Then click on Repair this PC

-) Click on Use a device and search for Windows Boot manager or something with Windows in its title.

after doing all these steps, you'll be booted to windows;
**no  single file will be deleted or apps changed **

### if else -follow these other set of steps below

*If you cannot find the Use a device option*, **reboot** **from** the USB and try again.

If still, you cannot find it, click on **Advanced Options**>**Command Prompt**

Then type the following commands one by one:

```
bootrec /fixmbr

bootrec /fixboot

exit
```

And **reboot** your computer (this will remove the grub bootloader from Windows)

Then just turn on your computer (do not boot from the USB)

Good luck! i will gladly follow up to check if you fixed the error

Comment: eh you assume he waited 3 years on you? "Last seen more than 3 years ago"  seriously doubt it

Comment: fortunately, I encountered the problem; on the same day I answered it so it'd be better for someone else not to struggle as i did,hope u get lol