# How can I install Ubuntu on a new computer without any OS and without a cd drive?

Tags: system-installation, usb-installation

I bought a new computer and I want to install Ubuntu on it. The computer doesn't have a CD drive or OS. I want Ubuntu to be the only OS on the computer.

So how can I install Ubuntu on a brand new computer?

Until now I was using a dual boot and I installed Ubuntu with a flash drive.

Comment: Since you have installed Ubuntu with a flash drive, the procedure is the same.

Comment: If a new system, then it should also be UEFI based. So you want to boot installer in UEFI boot mode to install in UEFI mode. UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu or partition during install:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Comment: Also have a look at [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) - it should still be valid. Especially note #5 where it says to tell your BIOS from where to boot (it then does not matter if it was CD or flash drive). Some BIOS also need booting from USB enabled.

Comment: Do you have a **smart phone**? You can use that to install Ubuntu to a PC. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/925400/how-to-install-ubuntu-using-a-smart-phone-as-the-installation-media

Answer (score 1):

### The Android app DriveDroid may be used to install Ubuntu to a computer using a smart phone

**No OS, USB, CD, DVD or friend required.**

The following is a quote of instructions given me by Kryštof Píštěk. You can thank him by upvoting his answer here https://askubuntu.com/a/925596/43926

1. Open the app and choose the + on the lower bar
2. Choose to download an image and to download Ubuntu and go through any additional steps
3. Go to the image list and choose the new Ubuntu option
4. If asked for emulation mode, choose read-only USB
5. Connect phone to PC if you haven't already and boot from the USB (depends on PC manufacturer)
6. (optional) When Ubuntu boots, choose to try Ubuntu, mount the Windows partition and move any files you want to rescue to the flash drive (if possible). If the partition is corrupted, look up a way to recover partitions in Linux
7. If you chose to skip 6, choose to Install ubuntu and follow the instructions on screen. If you followed 6, open the Install Ubuntu app on desktop and follow instructions on screen Note: While installing Ubuntu, you may want to remove the physical USB (so that you don't accidentally install on it)
8. Reboot, unplug your phone when asked to and enjoy!

The app DriveDroid is available on Google Play with searching or this link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softwarebakery.drivedroid

Answer (score 0):

You need some other PC to [write a bootable installation USB stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) (and a USB-Stick of course). I use [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en_US/) on Windows Systems and `dd` on linux systems.
Make sure the BIOS boot order is set to try booting from USB first.

You could also use a cd/dvd drive which is connected via USB.

Comment: Thank you! It's worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you have ubuntu Just use the App that came with ubuntu to create a new USB stick with ubuntu on it and install it from there

Answer (score 0):

Just download the ubuntu ISO on say the Desktop of another Linux machine. Then insert your usb and use the `fdisk -l` command to locate your usb...next step would be to use the dd command to write our iso to the usb:

`sudo dd if=/path/to/iso of=/path/to/usb`

Please make sure the 'of' part above points to your usb otherwise you might format our hard drive

and once this command is run successfully, you can use the usb for installation....Alternatively, if you have a windows computer around, use the procedure below coming from a video shared on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnisuFk-cDg&ab_channel=TechGeeks):

I hope this will help !