# Install Ubuntu without a USB flash drive or CD

Tags: boot, system-installation, unetbootin

I currently use Zorin OS and I want to switch to Ubuntu. If I try UNetbootin for Linux, it doesn't show any boot entry to install Ubuntu and I can't purchase a USB flash drive right now.

How can I install Ubuntu without a USB flash drive or CD?

Answer (score 2):

### Booting Ubuntu ISO from Zorin GRUB Menu

The method on this page should also work for booting an Ubuntu ISO from the Zorin GRUB bootloader  [20.04 booting .iso from GRUB menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251729/20-04-booting-iso-from-grub-menu/1251782#1251782)  No need for a USB here.

**To reiterate:**

- Add the following menuentry to grub.cfg:

  ```
  menuentry "isoname ISO" {
    set root=(hdX,Y)
    set isofile="/[path]/[isoname].iso"
        loopback loop $isofile
        linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile toram --
        initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
  }
  ```

Where `(hdX,Y)` is the disk and partition the ISO is on, `[path]` is the path to the folder the ISO file is in, and `[isoname]` is the name of the ISO

- Reboot and select Ubuntu from the grub menu. Install as usual.
- Please let us know how this works for you.
- Alternately you might also be able to install Ubuntu from your smart phone using DriveDroid, see: [How to install Ubuntu using a smart phone as the installation media?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925400/how-to-install-ubuntu-using-a-smart-phone-as-the-installation-media)

Comment: Maybe it is a good idea to use the boot option `toram`, if the user intends to overwrite the drive they boot from.

Comment: @sudodus: Yes of course.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the available drive? is not working, broken, showing up. If the assumption is that it's broken, try this first.

You could even use the USB you booted into the installer from BTW. And or a secondary HDD since Unetbootin allows for the use of HDDs.

Open GParted and format the drive, leave it as ext4. Uninstall Unetbootin `sudo apt-get remove unetbootin`. Install it again.

Hope you get around it! Cheers