# How to install ubuntu from phone?

Tags: boot, 21.04

I **haven't got any OS** on my system and I want to install ubuntu so I installed ubuntu 21.04 iso on my phone and I extracted it and I send it to a USB stick with a otg cable . But after inserting USB into laptop and pressing f12 and chossing USB nothing will happen .

Why and how can I fix it ?

Comment: You mention "*installed ubuntu 21.04 on my phone*" which I think is unlikely, it's more likely you downloaded & copied it to your phone (ie. it was on the phone only as a *datafile* and not installed) and then copied it to a thumb-drive (where it needs to be written so as to make it bootable, not just copied as a *datafile*; if written as a *datafile* it cannot be booted unless you have something already existing on your system that can read thumb-drives and chainload/pass-control to files on the media).  Copying a file is **not** the same as installing.

Comment: Try installing it using a different computer and rufus instead of your phone

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview

Comment: To Use your phone as a USB drive to install Ubuntu you can use DriveDroid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Install Ubuntu using a Smart Phone as the Installation Media

**Here is a reprint of instructions by Kryštof Píštěk for using DriveDroid to install Ubuntu.**

**Yes, it's possible** 
Using only an Android phone with internet, root and a USB Cable, you can emulate a flash drive with your Android phone using an app called DriveDroid. However, this is not officially supported and you may be better off asking a local Linux enthusiast (or anyone else who has a working computer) to burn a LiveCD/LiveUSB for you.

If you still want to use DriveDroid though, here is a tutorial:

1. Open the app and choose the + on the lower bar
2. Choose to download an image and to download Ubuntu and go through any additional steps
3. Go to the image list and choose the new Ubuntu option
4. If asked for emulation mode, choose read-only USB
5. Connect phone to PC if you haven't already and boot from the USB (depends on PC manufacturer)
6. (optional) When Ubuntu boots, choose to try Ubuntu, mount the Windows partition and move any files you want to rescue to the flash drive (if possible). If the partition is corrupted, look up a way to recover partitions in Linux
7. If you chose to skip 6, choose to Install ubuntu and follow the instructions on screen. If you followed 6, open the Install Ubuntu app on desktop and follow instructions on screen Note: While installing Ubuntu, you may want to remove the physical USB (so that you don't accidentally install on it)
8. Reboot, unplug your phone when asked to and enjoy!

The app DriveDroid is available on Google Play with searching or this link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softwarebakery.drivedroid

Ref: [How to install Ubuntu using a smart phone as the installation media?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925400/how-to-install-ubuntu-using-a-smart-phone-as-the-installation-media)