# How would I make a Raspberry Pi pretend to be a flash drive

Tags: usb, raspberrypi

So say I have a Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu on it.
And if I were to plug it in via USB A to USB A cable to another computer.
Or if it were attached via GPIO with a USB end and plug it into another computer.

How would I make it so that the computer think that the USB cable that is plug in to it is a vfat flash drive that it can read and write files.

Edit:
The file system of the drive would be on in a file so like a fat32 file system in file form and would be use when the external computer
reads the "flash drive"

Comment: Not even Android phones work that way since a long time ago.

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: Even if you could (can you?) what filesystem would the other computer access? Windows can't read ext4? What partition would it present?

Comment: but windows can read vfat or fat32

Comment: Not sure about an RPi but there is and app like what you want for Android. It is named **DriveDroid**: https://https://askubuntu.com/questions/925400/how-to-install-ubuntu-using-a-smart-phone-as-the-installation-media

Comment: drive droid looks like it does something like what i want to do but it is not open source so ya

Comment: but i do need it on a rpi